# Price value slider "on click" jQuery not working in mozilla firefox

Tags: jquery, wordpress, firefox

I have a slider displaying price values. The values changes both on slide and mouse click. Both of them work perfectly in google chrome, but on click function dosent work in firefox. on mouse click the value is not changing and displaying the initial value only. Here is my code:

```
jQuery("#bootstrap-slider").slider();
  jQuery("#bootstrap-slider").on("slide", function(slideEvt) {
    jQuery("#sliderValue").text(""+slideEvt.value+".00");
  });

  jQuery('.slider').on("click", function() {
    var newvalue = jQuery('.tooltip-inner').text();
    jQuery("#sliderValue").text(""+newvalue+".00");
    // jQuery('.tooltip-inner').text(""+newvalue+".00");
  });
```

can you tell me what to do attain the same functionality in firefox

Comment: check browser console and see what error you get. Also i think `jQuery('.tooltip-inner').text();` will always take value from the first slide tooltip, not the current slide, don't you think?

Comment: slide is functioning perfectly, its click that is messing up....

Comment: i am not talking about slide, it's about tooltip that you are capturing

Comment: the tool tip is capturing and displaying the right values

Comment: then check your mozila browser developer console while running the code and see if there is any error

Comment: There is no console error shown

Comment: you only have one slider?

Comment: @Stender yes ...

Comment: important question, since you are not using jQuery(this) or anything - so it would take the first tooltip it would find.... (...)